# VSCode liximomo sftp hop with public key authentication

Tags: visual-studio-code, sftp, openssh

Our web host has upgraded to OpenSSH 8.8, which has caused public keys to fail.
Putty 0.74, for example, can't authorize using an SSH private key, while Putty 0.76 can.

I assume liximomo sftp has this same issue, so I'm trying to work around the problem by using a hop to a system with OpenSSH 8.0, and from there hop to the web host.

My first attempt was to assume that sftp would forward the agent connection, so I used this sftp.json:

```
{
"name": "Pair",
"host": "my.server.com",
"port": 822,
"protocol": "sftp",
"username": "steve",
"agent": "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK",

"hop": {
    "host": "webhost.pairserver.com",
    "protocol": "sftp",
    "port": 22,
    "username": "company",
    "remotePath": "public_html"
}
}
```

This gets me to my server, but it fails with "All authentication methods failed" when attempting the hop.

I assumed this is because agent forwarding isn't working, so I put a private key on my server that will authenticate me to the webhost. I know the key works, because I can login to my server and run ssh on the command line with that key. But it still fails with an error like this:

```
[01-31 18:43:22] [error] Error: [webhost.pairserver.com]: All configured authentication methods failed
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:
SSH uses the "host key algorithm" to generate signatures for both the host keys and public key authentication. SSH clients and servers typically have "ssh-rsa" in this list.

The "ssh-rsa" algorithm uses SHA-1, which was broken in 2017. Therefore, it is not secure to continue to use this algorithm for purposes of public key authentication. It is still in the server's "host key algorithm" list, however, because it is also used for the host key. Using a broken SHA-1 algorithm for the host key cannot be used to break into as SSH server. (It could theoretically be used to impersonate an SSH server, but this is not a high risk, as most users blindly accept new host keys anyway.)
Therefore, OpenSSH 8.8 still includes "ssh-rsa" in the "host key algorithms" list, but a public key offered with the "ssh-rsa" algorithm will be ignored, as if that key was not in the authorized_keys file.

Older SSH clients do not include the "ssh-rsa2-*" algorithms, so they will continue to present public keys signatures with "ssh-rsa", which will be ignored.

Re-configuring the OpenSSH 8.8 host to accept "ssh-rsa" as a public key signature may be not possible, and for security reasons is not recommended, and probably wouldn't be allowed by a hosting company.

tl;dr There are 2 solutions to this problem:

1. Upgrade the client to a modern version that has the "ssh-rsa2-*" algorithms;
2. Switch to an ECDSA key.

Answer (score 0):

Generate your ssh key specifying the ecdsa algorithm type:
ssh-keygen -t ecdsa (Linux)
PuTTY (Windows)

```
{
"name": "your_remote_server_name",
"host": "123.456.789.100",
"protocol": "sftp",
"port": 1234,
"username": "remote_user_name",
"privateKeyPath": "/home/local_user_name/.ssh/id_ecdsa",
"passphrase":true,
"remotePath": "/home/remote_user_name/folderxyz",
"uploadOnSave": true,
"useTempFile": false,
"openSsh": false
}
```

If you don't use a passphrase when generating your ssh key, remove ("passphrase":true,) from this code.